# How to convert CFNetwork errors to NSURLErrorDomain?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, cfnetwork

NSURLConnection has some missing features (and some small bugs!), so I've been re-implementing it via CFNetwork. I'm aiming for a drop-in replacement - identical input, identical output.

Everything works great, except ... I can't find a way to map from CFNetwork error codes ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Reference/CFNetworkErrors/Reference/reference.html ) to the NSURLError codes ( https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html )

NB: *please* do not tell me to use ASIHttpRequest, AFNetworking, etc - I love them, I use them frequently, but ... for this specific project it's *not* possible to use any 3rd party code unless it's provided by Apple.